# SQL Server constraint won't save the way I define it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I noticed it before that SQL Server (or Management Studio) would "adjust" Check constraint when I create it via GUI. Most of the time it works OK and correct. But this particular constraint get changed every time. I even tried to do it in script but it would revert to incorrect one every time. Why?

This is what I run:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DSPTripAssignment] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_DSPTripAssignment_CarrierKey_DriverKey] 
  CHECK (([CarrierKey] IS NULL AND NOT [DriverKey] IS NULL) 
         OR ([DriverKey] IS NULL AND NOT [CarrierKey] IS NULL))
GO
```

This is what it reverts to (see missing braces around OR - kills logic)

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DSPTripAssignment] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_DSPTripAssignment_CarrierKey_DriverKey] 
  CHECK (([CarrierKey] IS NULL AND NOT [DriverKey] IS NULL 
         OR [DriverKey] IS NULL AND NOT [CarrierKey] IS NULL))
GO
```

Or, maybe you can suggest how to write this check better? I want to ensure that one of those keys specified but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't, in fact, kill the logic. In T-SQL, the [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190276) goes `NOT` > `AND` > `OR`, so

```
A AND NOT B OR C AND NOT D
```

is the same as

```
(A AND (NOT B)) OR (C AND (NOT D))
```

with redundant parentheses left out. Check definitions do get rewritten into a canonical form that may be less readable, but this does not result in an incorrect check.

Your actual check definition is fine -- although you can rewrite with `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`/`CASE`, this is likely to make the check less efficient. You can, however, rewrite `NOT X IS NULL` to `X IS NOT NULL`, which I'd consider more readable:

```
([CarrierKey] IS NULL AND [DriverKey] IS NOT NULL) OR ([DriverKey] IS NULL AND [CarrierKey] IS NOT NULL)
```

If you don't like the fact that SQL Server will rewrite the constraint, you can use a form that will not get rewritten:

```
([CarrierKey] IS NULL OR [DriverKey] IS NULL) AND ([DriverKey] IS NOT NULL OR [CarrierKey] IS NOT NULL)
```

And this can be split in two constraints, but since those don't make much sense on their own, I'd keep it together.

Comment: Putting NOT in front is just a habbit, will try to get rid of it. Precedence you listed makes sense but I don't thin result of it is readable..

I ended up breaking it into 2 constraints where one checks that at least one NULL and another checks that at least one NOT NULL

Comment: @katit: it isn't readable, but that shouldn't really matter. You can write the check the way you like; that SQL Server translates it to something different is a concern only if you script the check from the server again. There shouldn't be much need for that (you *do* keep your scripts around, right?)

Comment: No, I don't keem my scripts :) I design using Management studio and backup into SVN using RedGate. So, I do have scritps, but I have SQL Server scripts

Comment: @JeroenMostert: do you have a reference for the rewriting of the constraint that could be included in your answer?

Comment: @jmoreno: I'll have one for you as soon as Microsoft writes it up... in other words, no. To the best of my knowledge, the canonicalization process isn't documented. My speculation: the definition is parsed into a syntax tree in the same way the optimizer would do it in a query, and then either persisted as an internal format and pretty-printed on demand, or simply stored as the pretty-printed representation of the syntax tree.